# how to use 1 JSF page with different value of dataTable (2 managed_beans)

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a problem.
I have 2 managed beans : bean1 and bean2:

> -bean1 implements dataModel addedADS , where i have added ads by user.
>
> -bean2 implements dataModel choosenADS, where i have ads choosen by user

And you can see that bean1 and bean2 have the same variables but with different values because bean1 have ads and bean2 have ads but with different values. And what i want to do is i want use only 1 JSF page to show that values with dataTable but sometimes i need to show in my dataTable values of bean1 and sometimes i need to show values of bean2. How to do it ? now i have 2 JSF pages , one for bean1 and the other for bean2 , but this is the same JSF pages so it's not good to use 2 the same JSF pages. How to do it in 1 JSF page but with different values when i want it ? Now i use in 1 JSF page

```
<h:dataTable value=#{bean1.addedADS}
```

and in the other JSF page

```
<h:dataTable value=#{bean2.choosenADS}
```

How to use it in 1 JSF page? how to change that value when i want ?

Ok i paste my code and you can see what i have.

I have a template.xhtml where i set view of all my site and this is a part of menu where i download values from database:

```
         <div>
            <div id="left">
                <ul>
                        <li><a><span><h:link outcome="#{bean1.downloadChoosen()}" value="Ads choosen by user"/></span></a></li>
                        <li><a><span><h:link outcome="#{bean2.downloadAdded()}" value="Ads added by user"/></span></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="left_content">
                <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And in bean1 i have:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class bean1 {
    @EJB
    private Fasade fasade;

    private List<TChoosen> choosen=new ArrayList(); 
    private DataModel choosenData;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;

//here i download date and get list of objects
    public String downloadChoosen(){
        choosen=fasade.downloadChoosen();
        return "/faces/list_of_choosen_ads";
    }

//this method is started from JSF page list_of_choosen_ads
    public DataModel getChoosenData(){
        if(choosenData==null){
            choosenData=getPagination().createPageDataModel();
        }
        return choosenData;
    }

    public void setChoosenData(DataModel choosenData) {
        this.choosenData = choosenData;
    }

//this method is used for pagination and it's started from getChoosenData()
    public PaginationHelper getPagination(){
        if(pagination==null){
            pagination=new PaginationHelper(5){//5 its number of ads for 1pagination site


                @Override
                public int getItemsCount(){

                    return choosen.size();
                }

                @Override
                public DataModel createPageDataModel(){
                    int[] range={getPageFirstItem(),getPageLastItem()+1};
                    return new ListDataModel(findRange(range));

                }

            };
        }
        return pagination;
    }

//this method is used from getPagination() 
//ads_dto is my class used for data transfer object (just getters and setters)
    public ArrayList<ads_dto> findRange(int[] range){
        ArrayList<ads_dto> pom=new ArrayList();
        for(int i=range[0];i<range[1];i++){
            pom.add(ad_transform(choosen.get(i)));
        }
        return pom;
    }

    //this method is used by findRange() and its return dto object 
    //then in findRange() is created a list of dto objects
    public ads_dto ad_transform(TChoosen ch){
        ads_dto pom=new ads_dto();

        pom.setIdA(ch.getAdChoosen().getId());
        pom.setTitle(ch.getAdChoosen().getTitle());
        pom.setInformation(ch.getAdChoosen().getInformation());

        return pom;
    }

    private void recreateModel(){
        choosen=null;
    }

    //this is used for pagination        
    public String next(){
        getPagination().nextPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "/faces/list_of_choosen_ads";
    }
     //this is used for pagination     
    public String previous(){
        getPagination().previousPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "/faces/list_of_choosen_ads";
    }


    //and here just getters and setters where i input in JSF page values or get it 

    //id of ad
    public Long getIdA(){
        return ads_dto.getIdA();
    }

    public void setIdA(Long idA){
        this.ads_dto.setIdA(idA);
    }

    //title of ad
    public String getTitle() {
        return ads_dto.getTitle();
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.ads_dto.setTitle(title);
    }

    //information of ad
    public String getInfromation(){
         return ads_dto.getInformation();
    }

    public void setInformation(String information){
         this.ads_dto.setInformation(information);
    }
}
```

And in bean2 i have:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class bean2 {
        @EJB
        private Fasade fasade;

        private List<TAds> added=new ArrayList(); 
        private DataModel addedData;
        private PaginationHelper pagination;

    //here i download date and get list of objects
        public String downloadAdded(){
            added=fasade.downloadAdded();
            return "/faces/list_of_added_ads";
        }

    //this method is started from JSF page list_of_added_ads
        public DataModel getAddedData(){
            if(addedData==null){
                addedData=getPagination().createPageDataModel();
            }
            return addedData;
        }

        public void setAddedData(DataModel addedData) {
            this.addedData = addedData;
        }

    //this method is used for pagination and it's started from getChoosenData()
        public PaginationHelper getPagination(){
            if(pagination==null){
                pagination=new PaginationHelper(5){//5 its number of ads for 1pagination site


                    @Override
                    public int getItemsCount(){

                        return added.size();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public DataModel createPageDataModel(){
                        int[] range={getPageFirstItem(),getPageLastItem()+1};
                        return new ListDataModel(findRange(range));

                    }

                };
            }
            return pagination;
        }

    //this method is used from getPagination() 
    //ads_dto is my class used for data transfer object (just getters and setters)
        public ArrayList<ads_dto> findRange(int[] range){
            ArrayList<ads_dto> pom=new ArrayList();
            for(int i=range[0];i<range[1];i++){
                pom.add(ad_transform(added.get(i)));
            }
            return pom;
        }

        //this method is used by findRange() and its return dto object 
        //then in findRange() is created a list of dto objects
        public ads_dto ad_transform(TAds a){
            ads_dto pom=new ads_dto();

            pom.setIdA(a.getId());
            pom.setTitle(a.getTitle());
            pom.setInformation(a.getInformation());

            return pom;
        }

        private void recreateModel(){
            added=null;
        }

        //this is used for pagination        
        public String next(){
            getPagination().nextPage();
            recreateModel();
            return "/faces/list_of_added_ads";
        }
         //this is used for pagination     
        public String previous(){
            getPagination().previousPage();
            recreateModel();
            return "/faces/list_of_added_ads";
        }


        //and here just getters and setters where i input in JSF page values or get it 

        //id of ad
        public Long getIdA(){
            return ads_dto.getIdA();
        }

        public void setIdA(Long idA){
            this.ads_dto.setIdA(idA);
        }

        //title of ad
        public String getTitle() {
            return ads_dto.getTitle();
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.ads_dto.setTitle(title);
        }

        //information of ad
        public String getInfromation(){
             return ads_dto.getInformation();
        }

        public void setInformation(String information){
             this.ads_dto.setInformation(information);
        }
    }
```

And here is important parts of my 2 JSF pages

> 1: list_of_choosen_ads.xhtml

```
<!-- here i use my template -->
<ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
      <!-- here i show table when there is some data to show-->
      <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean1.pagination.itemsCount>0}">
        <!-- this is used for pagination-->
        <h:outputText value="#{bean1.pagination.pageFirstItem + 1}
                                      ..#{bean1.pagination.pageLastItem + 1}
                                      /#{bean1.pagination.itemsCount}"
                                      style="font-size: medium"/>&nbsp;
        <!-- this is used for pagination-->
        <h:commandLink action="#{bean1.previous}" 
                        value="#Previous #{bean1.pagination.pageSize}" 
                                rendered="#{bean1.pagination.hasPreviousPage}"
                                style="font-size: medium"/>&nbsp;
        <!-- this is used for pagination-->
        <h:commandLink action="#{bean1.next}" 
                                value="next #{bean1.pagination.pageSize}" 
                                rendered="#{bean1.pagination.hasNextPage}"
                                style="font-size: medium"/>&nbsp;

        <!-- here is my table where i use my dataModel choosenData and i show in table columns idA, Title, Information-->
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean1.choosenData}" 
                                     var="item" border="0"
                                     cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"
                                     rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row"
                                     rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">

            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="idA"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{item.idA}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Title"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Information"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{item.Information}"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

> 2: list_of_added_ads.xhtml

```
<!-- here i use my template -->
<ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
      <!-- here i show table when there is some data to show-->
      <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean2.pagination.itemsCount>0}">
        <!-- this is used for pagination-->
        <h:outputText value="#{bean2.pagination.pageFirstItem + 1}
                                      ..#{bean2.pagination.pageLastItem + 1}
                                      /#{bean2.pagination.itemsCount}"
                                      style="font-size: medium"/>&nbsp;
        <!-- this is used for pagination-->
        <h:commandLink action="#{bean2.previous}" 
                        value="#Previous #{bean2.pagination.pageSize}" 
                                rendered="#{bean2.pagination.hasPreviousPage}"
                                style="font-size: medium"/>&nbsp;
        <!-- this is used for pagination-->
        <h:commandLink action="#{bean2.next}" 
                                value="next #{bean2.pagination.pageSize}" 
                                rendered="#{bean2.pagination.hasNextPage}"
                                style="font-size: medium"/>&nbsp;

        <!-- here is my table where i use my dataModel addedData and i show in table columns idA, Title, Information-->
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean2.addedData}" 
                                     var="item" border="0"
                                     cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"
                                     rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row"
                                     rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">

            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="idA"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{item.idA}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Title"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:outputText value="Information"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{item.Information}"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And this is it. Like you can see JSF page 1 and 2 are the same and have the same columns in table but use different dataModel. And what i need to do is use only 1 JSF page. And when someone click in menu "Ads choosen by user" ( like i show menu in template.xhtml) i want to show on that 1 JSF Page values from bean1, and when someone click in menu "Ads added by user" i want to show on the same JSF page values from bean2. Not like now when i have 2 JSF page. And this is my problem. I am start with Java EE and maybe its simple to do but i have problem with that.

Comment: Do `addedADS` and `choosenADS` classes extend from the same class, are they the same class or are totally different classes?

Comment: addedADS and choosenADS have the same values from class TAds but choosenADS take it from TChoosen where is reference for the TAds. So
class TAds have: 
-Long id;
-String title;
-String information;
-TUsers user; - this is reference to user who create that Ad so i can use it for search ads of 1 user.

And class TChoosen have: 
-Long id;
-TAds ad; - this is ad which was added by some user (This information is in TAds).
-TUsers user; - this is reference to user who choosen ad